# Call the jvectormap's addMarker function

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I'm using the jVectorMap plugin and I'd like to trigger a marker by another function.
How can I call just that one line  `map.addMarker( index, markers[index], [values1[index], values2[index]] );`  ?

```
$("#target").click(function() {
**Here should that addMarker function included**
});
```

That's the part of the code where the markers are triggerd by a checkbox:

```
            $('.list-markers :checkbox').change(function(){

                var index = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-marker-index');

                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    map.addMarker( index, markers[index], [values1[index], values2[index]] );
                } else {
                    map.removeMarkers( [index] );
                }
            });
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand you use the new version of jVectorMap, which haven't been released yet. To get access to the `addMarker` method you need an instance of `jvm.WorldMap`. If you created map through the plug-in call (`$('#map').vectorMap()`) you can use the following syntax to get it:

```
$('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. What exactly is 'get' and what's the 'mapObject'?    So let's say I have the following code `$("#target").click(function() {
$('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
});
`

Comment: Hi, I tried it but without success. I included it in the following code  `$("#target").click(function() {
var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject'); map.addMarker( index, markers[0], [values1[0], values2[0]] );
});`   On click the marker should be added. Are these lines ok?

Comment: This is the right answer and thank you for it. The author's documentation is not very clear and more updated examples would be appreciated.